# How can I display a custom text selection action on empty text field in android

Tags: android, android-intent, textfield

I know Intent.PROCESS_TEXT insert your option in the pop-up when the user makes a text selection. but how I can insert an option like the "paste" option inside the pop-up, even when a text field is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback` in API 11 or above for example:

```
edittext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {

    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {                  
    }

    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.selection, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

and

[image]

> selection.xml in menus:

```
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:title="Test" />
 </menu>
```

**finally**:

[image]

Comment: Okay, what if you are trying to make it global across apps?.

Comment: Dear Abdullahi, you can not do this.